# Question on maintaining different water levels with one pump

Tags: fluid-dynamics

is it possible , or how is it possible ( with valves etc.. ) to maintain water at two different levels ( in two separate open vessels ) that are circulated  with one pump

see diagram

[image]

Comment: There will be evaporation, and you haven't shown any makeup water in your drawing.

Answer (score 0):

A float valve will maintain a constant water level in a tank of water. A single pressure line branched off to multiple tanks at different levels, with a float valve at each tank will maintain their individual levels, as long as the line supply meets the demand. A float valve consists of a lever on a valve, with a float on one end of the lever. When the water level drops slightly, the valve opens, allowing in more water. As the level rises slightly the float will close the valve, maintaining the water level. If you only want to circulate water in two tanks at two levels, pump water from the lower tank into the higher tank, then let an upper level drain pipe gravity feed water back to the lower tank. The water will circulate as long as the pump runs. The water level in the lower tank may lower from evaporation or other losses, if not replenished.

Answer (score 0):

If constant circulation is part of the challenge, float valves might not be the solution.

However, there are at least two other solutions.  One uses the [venturi effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect) in which there is a pressure drop in a section of a pipe where the pipe diameter is reduced.  The other uses the fact that there is a pressure drop across, e.g., a [partially closed valve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNTs3xH_WHw).  In either solution, vertical pipes from the high- and low- pressure sections of the flow would feed the two different reservoirs. The height difference between the reservoirs would be proportional to the pressure drop, which is roughly proportional to the rate of fluid flow, with the proportionality constant depending on the amount of diameter reduction in the venturi case and on the amount of constriction in the case of a partially closed valve.